# add hyperlink to a column in igx-grid

Tags: angular, infragistics, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I want to know how can I add a hyperlink to a single column in igx-grid?
Here is a sample data:

```js
  export const DATA: any[] = [
    {
     OrderID: 10524,
     SaleAmount: 3192.65,
     CategoryName: "Beverages",
     CompanyName: "Berglunds snabbköp",
     ShipCountry: "France",
     ShippedDate: new Date("1997-05-07T00:00:00Z"),
     Website: "https://www.infragistics.com/"
   },
   {
     OrderID: 10511,
     SaleAmount: 2550.0,
     CategoryName: "Beverages",
     CompanyName: "Bon app'",
     ShipCountry: "France",
     ShippedDate: new Date("1997-04-21T00:00:00Z"),
     Website: "https://www.google.com/"
   },
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyperlinks could be added in igxCell via using [cell templates](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/grid#cell-template):

```html
<igx-column field="Website" header="Website" [dataType]="'string'" [minWidth]='"200px"'>
    <ng-template igxCell let-cell="cell">
        <a class="truncate" href="{{cell.value}}" target="_blank">{{cell.value}}</a>
    </ng-template>
</igx-column>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/igx-grid-cell-hyperlinks) you can find a stackblitz sample demonstrating how to achieve the required behavior.

Additionally, all the IgxCell’s properties are listed in the Infragistics documentation [here](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxcell.html) and more about IgxColumnComponent can be found [here](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxcolumncomponent.html).